# System.IO.IO.Exception: The specified path invalid

Tags: c#, debugging, exception, visual-studio-2022, unhandled-exception

Why am I getting a `System.IO.IOException` when debugging my C# application using Visual Studio 2022?

My application arguments are `--target_path="P:\ExampleTesting\ExampleTesting\bin\Debug\net5.0\ExampleTesting.exe" "P:\testcases"`

Could any one help me to solve this problem?

And also, I added in my project the dll path of two libraries from source code.

[image].
[image]

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: How are you parsing the command line arguments? The error shows that the path it's trying to locate is `P:\ExampleTesting...\--target_path=P:\ExampleTesting\...` which is invalid.

Comment: I am parsing the command line arguments as in the above first image during debugging. I am running using the winsharp command along with the command line arguments in the powershell.

Comment: No. The first image shows you _setting_ command line arguments to _pass in to the program_ when the program executes. You don't show how you're _parsing_ the command line arguments (the `args` varaible from the Main parameters).

Comment: it would be so much easier if we could see that 'main' functions, please post code

Comment: static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Fuzzer.LibFuzzer.Run(bytes => 
            {
                
                using (var ms  = new MemoryStream(bytes.ToArray()))
                {
                     Target function to fuzz; 
                 }                                                                                                                                         });